# SwiftにおけるSelector(SEL)の比較

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

OS XにおいてObjective-CのコードをSwiftに書き換えています。

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem
{
    SEL action = menuItem.action;

    if(action == @selector(reloadContent:)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

上記の-validateMenuItem:を書き換えようと思ったのですがSELの比較をSwiftでどのように書けばよいのか分かりません。
Swiftではどのように書けばよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swiftでは、

```
"reloadContent:"
```

のような文字列リテラルが`SEL`として扱われます。

このことから、「文字列＝セレクタ」と誤解する向きがありますが、これはコンパイラによる特別扱いで、実際には文字列リテラルから`Selector`構造体が作られています。

`Selector`構造体の定義を読めば分かりますが、`StringLiteralConvertible`プロトコルに準拠しています。ですので、文字列リテラルと比較することは可能です。

ただし、

```
if menuItem.action == "reloadContent:" {
    return true
}
```

のような処理で、`StringLiteralConvertible`としての比較が優先されるのか、`"reloadContent:"`がコンパイラに特別扱いされ`Selector`型同士で同値比較されているのかは、実装次第なので外部から判断が付かない気がします。

その他、移植されたObjective-Cランタイム関数を用いて、

```
sel_isEqual(menuItem.action, "reloadContent:" )
```

で比較することもできます。

---

**EDIT:**

本題から外れますが、@Harawo さんの回答の「文字列定数は、自動でSelectorに変換される」という解釈は誤りですので、それを説明するPlayground上で実行できる、簡単なコードを掲載しておきます。（実行環境はXCode 6.3beta、Swift1.2です）

```
let aSelector : Selector = "action:"    //型宣言したセレクタ
let aConstant : String = "action:"      //文字列定数
var aString = "action:"                 //型推論させる


aSelector == "action:"  // true
aConstant == "action:"  // true

aSelector == aConstant  // compilation error
aSelector == aString    // compilation error!!
```

文字列定数、というと一般には`let`で宣言した`String`をイメージしますので、その前提で話をしますが、**Swiftには型の暗黙変換が一切存在しない** ので、文字列定数と`Selector`構造体を比較した場合、`Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Selector' and 'String'`というコンパイルエラーになります。

あくまで比較できるのは**文字列リテラル**（リテラルとは、ソースコード中に直接記述されているもの）だけです。文字列、文字列定数とは比較できません。

余談として、型推論させた場合でも`String`として解釈されてエラーになります。

一方で、「Swiftには型の暗黙変換が存在しない」という前言と矛盾しますが、Objective-Cとの互換のために、`Selector`構造体はC文字列（オペイクポインタである`SEL`の実体）との間で相互に変換することができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます  
`Selector`構造体をキーに調べてみました  
比較を明確にするには  
`if action == Selector("reloadContent:") `  
のように明示的にSelectorにするのがよいと思われました

Answer (score 2):

文字列と比較します。

```
let action:Selector = menuItem.action

if action == "reloadContent:" {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[iOS Developer Library

Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C

Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_25)

この中の項「Objective-C Selectors」から引用します。

> An Objective-C selector is a type that refers to the name of an
>   Objective-C method. In Swift, Objective-C selectors are represented by
>   the Selector structure. You can construct a selector with a string
>   literal, such as let mySelector: Selector = "tappedButton:". Because
>   string literals can be automatically converted to selectors, you can
>   pass a string literal to any method that accepts a selector.

文字列定数は、自動でSelectorに変換されると、Appleが公式文書で述べているのですから、そのとおり

```
menuItem.action == "reloadContent:"
```

で、なんらかまわないと思いますよ。考えすぎて、得なことはありません。

Comment: 特に否定も肯定もしないのですけど、Stringリテラルをセレクタと推論する言語仕様は、ビルドが重い大きな要因だと思うので、コンパイラにヒントを与えても利はあっても害はないと思いますね。